# Converting Dataset to Xml file

Tags: c#

I have added DataSet at design time by 'Add -> New Item -> DataSet -> DataSet1.xsd'
So, I have added all the required tables along with setting their 1:1 or 1:M relations.

When I write this DataSet to XML file using WriteXml(), I get something like -

```
<Term>
  <TermId>1</TermId>
  <Title>Term1</Title> 
  <ContactTeacher>
    <TermId>1</TermId>
    <FirstName>A1</FirstName>
    <LastName>A1L</LastName>
  </ContactTeacher>
  <ContactTeacher>
      <TermId>1</TermId>
      <FirstName>B1</FirstName>
      <LastName>B1L</LastName>
  </ContactTeacher>
</Term>
```

So, as you see in above Xml, child table 'ContactTeacher' is having its FK column TermId appearing in the output.
I am having this TermId column in child table to set relation between the tables.

Is there anyway I can avoid FK columns from Child tables to result in output XML?
Or should I go for generating customized Xml output from Dataset tables - Is Linq to XML is a good choice to handle this?

Comment: Please don't prefix your code with "c# - .net 3.5" - that's what tasks are for.